# How do I get the entire page's HTML with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I used `$(document).html()`, but that threw an error...  is there a way to get everything?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You could try:

```
$("html").html();
```

If you want to also capture the html tags you could concatenate them to the html like this:

```
function getPageHTML() {
  return "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
}
```

Comment: how about getting the doctype?

Comment: @Sebastian Not sure if you can, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043820/jquery-check-doctype)

Comment: This could work, but if you're replacing a page with a whole other page, you'll end up having multiple html tags.

Answer (score 71):

**Edit: Use [XMLSerializer()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58778175/437)**

Don't forget the `<html>` tag can have attributes too. If you want the whole document this should work.

```
 $('html')[0].outerHTML
```

It's also trivial without jQuery.

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

---

If you also want to [include the doctype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088972/get-doctype-of-an-html-as-string-with-javascript), it's a little more involved.

```
var getDocTypeAsString = function () { 
    var node = document.doctype;
    return node ? "<!DOCTYPE "
         + node.name
         + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '')
         + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') 
         + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '')
         + '>\n' : '';
};

getDocTypeAsString() + document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
document.body.innerHTML
```

Comment: If you want the entire document html you should use:
`window.document.innerHTML`

Comment: @simo: `document` doesn't have an `innerHTML` property in any browsers i still use.

Answer (score 3):

No need to lean on jQuery. The best and simplest approach is to use

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document)
```

which will always give you the contents of the entire page **including** DOCTYPE tag, and it is supported in all modern browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=xml-serializer

Answer (score 2):

`$("html").html()` would get everything but the outer most html tags.

Comment: What does this anwer have more than the accepted answer?