# jQuery check doctype

Tags: jquery, doctype

```
If doctype is <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    // do something
else 
    // do something
```

How to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, I'm back after testing this in IE, Chrome, Firefox and Opera.  IE will give you the full doctype with the following piece of code:

```
var doctype = document.documentElement.previousSibling.nodeValue;
// -> DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
```

Unfortunately, this is probably incorrect, as Chrome, Firefox and Opera return `null` for `nodeValue`.  Since none of them support `outerHTML`, I can't think of a way to get the full doctype, but you can get individual parts:

```
 var doctype = document.documentElement.previousSibling;

 console.log(doctype.systemId)
 // -> http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd

 console.log(doctype.publicId)
 // -> -//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN
```

However, that doesn't work in IE, but it wouldn't be too difficult to parse those out.  You can use an `if` statement to check that `nodeValue` is not `null` and fall back to checking `systemId` or `publicId`.

Script used to run the tests: http://jsfiddle.net/Cwb8q/

Comment: just for curiosity: try `$(document).siblings();` -> **ups**

Comment: @jAndy: error for me in Chrome. `$(document.documentElement).siblings()` doesn't error, but it doesn't contain the doctype in the results.

Comment: 's head: I receive an error aswell, that was the "ups" part. Either Mr. Resig forgot to check for that or he just assumed that this approach is just so useless no one would ever try :)

Comment: @jAndy: I think it's probably a combination of both, it probably didn't occur to him.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [jQuery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) object to check for specific browser features (e.g. BoxModel) and working against them.

Comment: Checking for real capability (instead of advertised capability) is indeed the only way to retain sanity.

Answer (score 2):

`document.doctype` and `document.firstChild` both seem to return the doctype, though I do not know how widely supported they are.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the attribute "this.document.doctype"
If the  isn't declared, the result will be null, otherwise, the result will be the object with the doctype.

Answer (score -5):

You could try:

var doc = $("DOCTYPE");

Comment: That does not work. Using `$('DOCTYPE')` always returns `[]`, and properly including the exclamation mark, i.e. writing `$('!DOCTYPE')`, results in a syntax error: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: !DOCTYPE`.