# Automatically adding the 'alt' attribute to every image on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, alt

I have a requirement to add the `alt` attribute to each of the images on each of my web pages. The problem is that there are **hundreds** of images on some of those web pages.

Can anyone suggest an approach using JavaScript or jQuery that, for each image on a page, copies the name of the image (minus the extension) to a new `alt` attribute?

**Before:**

```html
<img src="android.jpg width="100" height="50" />
```

**After** (exclude ".jpg")**:**

```html
<img src="android.jpg width="100" height="50" alt="android" />
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').each(function(){
    var $img = $(this);
    var filename = $img.attr('src')
    $img.attr('alt', filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
  });
});
```

You could ask before if alt attribute doesn't [already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318076/jquery-hasattr-checking-to-see-if-there-is-an-attribute-on-an-element) by adding:

```
var attr = $(this).attr('alt');
    if (typeof attr == typeof undefined || attr == false) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, how can I paste some HTML code and click a button to run this script, final output the script? like this http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier

Comment: This will run when the page loads. If you want to change it to run on a button click then replace `$(document).ready(function() {` with `$('#buttonId').bind('click', function() {` (replacing #buttonId with the correct selector)

Comment: I don't want to run this script every time when user browse this page, so can I get this updated source code and paste it on the page?

Comment: You would need to use something like this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982717/how-do-i-get-the-entire-pages-html-with-jquery

Comment: I think it would be nice if you add a breakdown of what's happening for those of us that are learning javascript or jQuery.  For example, I was able to follow it all, up until the filename.substring part.  I think it's important that people are able to actually learn and understand answers, other than just copy/paste them and be like, "okay it works, cool.  Don't know why, but it works".  Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a JavaScript approach:

```js
function runScript() {
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("img").length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].setAttribute(
            "alt", document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].src);
    }
}
```

Run the function `runScript()` once the page is loaded!

Comment: However, adding alt on clientside by JavaScript does not really help you all that much. For one thing, Google won't see them. For another, the text-only browsers like lynx (which are most likely to need alt) won't see them. You only gain a little bit of benefit on accessibility, but even that is lost unless you have really really nice image file names.

Answer (score 0):

This script can help you to get your work handled. It will append the filename of image in alt attribute

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>  
 <script type='text/javascript'>  
 //<![CDATA[  
 $(document).ready(function() {  
  $('img').each(function(){  
   var $img = $(this);  
   var filename = $img.attr('src')  
   $img.attr('title', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));  
   $img.attr('alt', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));  
  });  
 });  
 //]]>  
 </script>
```