# jQuery Ajax Page Loading Fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want when I click a link with attribute "linkdata" = "page" to change the body's code to a loading image and after it's done to change the whole document's HTML to the result. Here is the current code I have:

```
$('a[linkdata="page"]').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function () {
    var attribute = $(this).attr("href");
    $("body").html('<center><img src="/ajax-loader.gif" /></center>');
    $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: attribute }).done(function (data) { 
      $(document).html(data); 
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

The result:
It changes the body's HTML code to the image and always fails with the request (which is http://somelink.com/home - using CodeIgniter, tried with `.fail(function() { window.location="/error/404" });`)

Comment: write like this `$('a[linkdata="page"]').click(function() {` .. don't write each & then click function.

Comment: There is more code to that object, that's why I use .each before it.

Comment: Not trolling, just curious for learning purposes - What is the point of refreshing the entire document via ajax as opposed to just linking to the page or forcing a refresh?

Comment: Looks like there might be some limitation preventing you from accessing or setting `$(document).html()`: http://jsfiddle.net/qL3sE/. This person has trouble as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982717/how-do-i-get-the-entire-pages-html-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[linkdata="page"]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("body").html('<center><img src="/ajax-loader.gif" /></center>');
  $.ajax({url:$(this).attr("href") })
   .success(function(data){$(document.body).html(data);})
   .error(function(x,s,e){alert('Warning! '+s+': '+e)});
});
```

Comment: Please see http://jsfiddle.net/NE6aC/. Somehow you get always a kind of error with empty responseText

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[linkdata="page"]').on('click',function(k,v){
   var attribute = $(this).attr("href");
   $("body").html('<center><img src="/ajax-loader.gif" /></center>');
    $(document).load({ type: "GET", url: attribute });
  })
```

Comment: No change in the result again.

Comment: Could you eleborate why this is the solution?