# jQuery get entire iframe source including comments outside <html>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

The question [How do I get the entire page's HTML with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982717/how-do-i-get-the-entire-pages-html-with-jquery) might look similar, which helps in obtaining data from `<html>` and `<!DOCTYPE>`. But in addition, I also require to obtain any comments that persist before the `<html>` tag.

I am displaying the page with the help of srcdoc attribute using jQuery. My current code to obtain the data is

```
$("#myiframe").contents().find('html')[0].outerHTML;
```

and a snippet in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12523515/1493858) to obtain `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Sample use case:

```
<!-- 
  This comment will be used for further processing
--> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
<!-- 
  This comment will be used for further processing
-->
```

The current output is only from `<!DOCTYPE html>` to `</html>`. Expected to have the comments outside.

Comment: `$.ajax(location).then(alert.bind(window))`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jQuery's `$.get` function.  This basically returns everything you would retrieve with a normal `GET` request.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

**Try this:**

```
$('iframe#myiframe').load(function() {
  getFrameContent(this.contentWindow.location);
});

function getFrameContent(windowURL) {
   $.get( windowURL, function( data ) {
     //where 'data' is the page contents
     $( "#whateverElementYouWant" ).html( data );
  });
}
```

Comment: Tried and ended up with the error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load about:srcdoc. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`. My `$("#myiframe").get(0).contentWindow.location` gives `about:srcdoc`

Comment: Updated my answer with a slightly different option.  Should update the `windowURL` variable whenever the page in your `<iframe>` is changed.  What are you trying to do with the HTML once you get it?